# Free software remote assistance tool for double NAT

Tags: remote, vnc, teamviewer

I need a remote assistance tool (i.e. tool that makes it possible to control another persons screen) that:

1. works between two machines that are both NAT'ed behind different NAT-walls
2. does not require modification of NAT-wall (i.e. port forwarding is no-go)
3. works as both client and server on both Windows 7+XP and GNU/Linux
4. is free (as in freedom - not price) software

It should preferably survive if any of the machines change its internal IP address (e.g. as part of a DHCP change).

TeamViewer delivers 1, 2, and 3, but fails 4 because of its license.

Google Chrome Remote Desktop delivers 1, 2, and 3, but fails 4 because of its license.

The different VNC tools deliver 3 and 4, but fails for either 1 or 2.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: This answer is only valid for non commerical usage, apologies.

I've used Mikogo for free remote desktop sharing - it get's around NAT by having both ends of the session independantly connect to their server in the cloud which then links them.

Only nuisance is that you need to get the user to load a web page, enter the session id, then run the client, although I've managed to get very non technical people to do this over the phone.

Only one of your requirements I haven't tested myself is use with Linux, although looking up on the net, this appears to be possible.

Also would note, that shopping questions are off topic so I thought this would have been closed but if a 44k user has edited the question and kept it open then it might somehow stay open.

Comment: According to the pricing page, it doesn't appear to be free software.

Comment: @ Jay - On this page you can download the s/w needed to do it for free http://www.mikogo.com/download/windows-download/ However I'm sorry I've noticed something that may be an issue for you "Free Version - This version is hosted with the free version of Mikogo. We kindly ask you to purchase a business license if you use Mikogo for commercial purposes"

Comment: I was thinking about deleting my answer as this doesn't fit all the required criteria, but I thought I may was well leave it in case it helps someone else in the future.

Comment: Yeah, I inferred it was needed for commercial reasons or TeamViewer would fit the bill perfectly. I don't think it's feasible to meet all the requirements simultaneously, and given that this is more flexibly priced it might be an option (but borders more on shopping).

Comment: Also Mikogo is not free software as per the Free Software definition (it is only zero cost - not free as freedom).